# compare a number to one of more numbers using OR in python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why python is printing false when the if condition is being satisfied. What am I missing ? Please advise

```
s
Out[147]: '936100'

if int(s[0:4]) == 9361 | 9363:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"

false

int(s[0:4])
Out[149]: 9361
```

Comment: `|` is bitwise or operator. I don't think you wanted that?

Comment: Agreed with @hqkhan, if you are thinking of using or just type `or`

Comment: @Ahtisham In his case the list is a string of numerals, which you can pass as an argument to int(). Try it for yourself: `>>> int("123456"[0:4])`
`1234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is bitwise or operator in python. The logical `OR` is done using built-in `or` in python.

```
s = '936100'

if (int(s[0:4]) == 9361) or (int(s[0:4]) == 9363):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')

# true
```

`9361 | 9363 = 9363`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things going on here. Let's go over them one at a time.

First, there is the issue of Python's order of operations. The bitwise or operator `|` is evaluated before the comparison `==` operator. In other words, the line `if int(s[0:4]) == 9361 | 9363` is equivalent to `if int(s[0:4]) == (9361 | 9363)`.

For another, I suspect that `|` isn't what you intend to use here. In this context, `|` is the [bitwise or](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) operator, not the logical or. In other words, it's taking the bitwise or of 9361 and 9363, which is 9363. What you should be using in this context is the `or` keyword, like this:

```
if int(s[0:4]) == 9361 or int(s[0:4]) == 9363:
```

Unfortunately there's no way to see if something equals one object or another without testing multiple times.

If you wish to avoid doing that, one thing you can do is see if the set `{9361, 9363}` contains the value.

```
if int(s[0:4]) in {9361, 9363}:
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if int(s[0:4]) == 9361 | 9363`, use `if int(s[0:4]) in {9361, 9363}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if int(s[0:4]) == 9361 or int(s[0:4]) == 9363:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Is probably what you wanted.

Also, notice that:

```
>>> x = 9361 | 9363
>>> x
9363
```